# Why do I get "NameError: name '...' is not defined" in python module?

Tags: python, machine-learning

**filename:recom.py**

```
# Returns a distance-based similarity score for person1 and person2
def sim_distance(prefs,person1,person2):
# Get the list of shared_items
    si={}
    for item in prefs[person1]:
        if item in prefs[person2]:
            si[item]=1
    # if they have no ratings in common, return 0
    if len(si)==0: return 0
    # Add up the squares of all the differences
    sum_of_squares=sum([pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2)
    for item in prefs[person1] if item in prefs[person2]])
    return 1/(1+sum_of_squares)
```

Am getting the error ,when i try to do ***reload(recom)***

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'recom' is not defined**

Comment: Did you `import recom` before?

Comment: no i just did ` from recom import critics`(critics was a dictionary).Thanks for the heads up!. problem fixed!

Answer (score 2):

I use python 3.4.3, and I just encountered the same problem. The below solution solved it for me.

When you use `reload()` you should also use `from imp import reload` before you use it.

As to  getting the Euclidean Distance Score, you can get your answer like:

```
 from recom import critics
 from recom import sim_distance
 sim_distance(critics,'Lisa Rose','Gene Seymour')
```

The result is: 0.29429805508554946

Answer (score 1):

You need to have imported the module using "import recom" before it can be reloaded.  Also, make sure the code is executing where it can resolve the path to recom.