# Reload Python module

Tags: python

I am new to python and I have an issue with compiling the example code in Programming Collective Intelligence book which I am currently reading.

I first make a file called `recommendations.py` and add a dictionary with data of movies and their rating by people.

then in python intrepreter

```
 >> from recommendations import critics 
 >> critics['SomeName']
 I get the data from the dictionary.
```

Now, the books asks me to add the code

```
from math import sqrt
def sim_distance(prefs,person1,person2):
 si={}
 for item in prefs[person1]:
 if item in prefs[person2]:
 si[item]=1
  if len(si)==0: return 0
 sum_of_squares=sum([pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2)
 for item in prefs[person1] if item in prefs[person2]])
 return 1/(1+sum_of_squares)
```

then in intrepreter I am asked to `reload(recommendations)` but I get `NameError: 'recommendations' not defined`

What is the issue? The recommendations.py contains the critics dictionary and also the code. The `from recommendations import critics` works, but reload does not work. I am new to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a conceptual problem here.  `recommendations.py` is a file.  From the way your code uses it, we can deduce that it defines [a module](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) - it is a *module source file*.  You can load the module by writing `import recommendations` - you then have a *module object* in your session named recommendations.  If you do that, then you can also reload the module using `reload(recommendations)`.  Note that reload will *only* work on a *module object* that has previously been imported from its *module source file*.  It will not read the file for the first time and import the module. See [the documentation for reload](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) where it explains that.

In your case, you have not imported the module - you have imported a particular component of the module (`critics`) by using the line `from recommendations import critics`.  Therefore, the interpreter session does not contain anything called `recommendations` and tells you so by giving the error you saw (`NameError: 'recommendations' not defined`).

My guess is that the book (I haven't got access to it), somewhere in the preceding code, has told you to type `import recommendations`.  You must do this in the same interpreter session as where you type reload(recommendations) in order for the reload to work.

***EDIT:***

I have just noticed that the same question [is posed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970835/why-do-i-get-nameerror-name-is-not-defined-in-python-module) - it looks like there might be a problem in the book that it doesn't work if you just follow it through.

Answer (score 1):

The `reload()` works on modules (e.g. recommendations.py)

To reload `recommendations`, you can do like this:

```
import recommendations
# use recommendations.critics['name']
```

Then  `reload(recommendations)`

The issue was that when you do `from recommendations import critics`, you've imported `critics` which was probably just a value inside your recommendations.py file, and not a module (not a critics.py file inside a recommendations folder). `reload` works on modules, doesn't work on objects inside a module

Comment: i do have recommendations.py file. So reload() must work right?

Comment: From python documentation `reload`"If a module imports objects from another module using from ... import ..., calling reload() for the other module does not redefine the objects imported from it — one way around this is to re-execute the from statement, another is to use import and qualified names (module.*name*) instead."

Comment: @bakkal Jup, I saw it and wanted to add the reason from the python documentation for completeness of your answer

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer! Unless the site doesn't allow you, then I'll edit it with a quote from the documentation