# Need to re-load libraries in Python, with Canopy

Tags: python, python-2.7, canopy

I am working on a python project with Canopy, using my own library, which I modify from time to time to change or add functions inside.

At the beginning of `myfile.py` I have `from my_library import *` but if I change a function in this library and compute again `myfile.py` it keep using the previous version of my function.

I tried the `reload` function :

```
import my_library
reload(my_library)
from other_python_file import *
from my_library import *
```

and it uses my recently changed library.

But if it is :

```
import my_library
reload(my_library)
from my_library import *
from other_python_file import *
```

It gives me the result due to the version loaded the first time I launched `myfile.py`.

Why is there a different outcome inverting the 3rd and 4th line ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload Python module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899348/reload-python-module)

Comment: @Simakis Panagiotis : The problem in the question you mention is that there is no "import my_module" but I put it. That's not the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the source code, it's hard to be certain. (For future reference, it is most useful to post a minimal example, which I suspect would be about 10 lines of code in this case.)

However from your description of the problem, my guess is that your `other_python_file` also imports `my_library`. So when you do `from other_python_file import *`, you are also importing everything that it has already imported from `my_library`, which in your second example, will override the imports directly from `my_library` (Since you didn't reload `other_python_file`, it will still be using the previous version of `my_library`.)

This is one out of approximately a zillionteen reasons why you should almost never use the form `from xxx import *` except on the fly in interactive mode (and even there it can be dangerous but can be worth the tradeoff for the convenience). In a python source file, there's no comparable justification for this practice. See the final point in the [Imports section of PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: (Edited answer to explain why other_python_file still uses previous version of my_library)